# How to model a pool of available VLAN IDs in UML

Tags: uml

I have a network with a finite number of VLAN IDs available, lets say 4000. Each VLAN corresponds to a single service. Each time I create a service, a VLAN will be consumed. When the service is decommissioned, the VLAN will become available.

I am wondering what the best way is to model this in UML.

Do you create a class for VLAN ID and instantiate it 4000 times with some sort of uniqueness constraint so you cannot have the same VLAN ID twice?

Comment: I answered, but next time provide a schema to show what you try.

Comment: Would you mind to specify what you mean by _range_ ?

Comment: and why do you use networking and sdn tags ?

Comment: @user2693916 your suggestion is not bad, a VLAN class and a manager of VLAN list. Then you have to model the list of available VLAN. So now can you propose your own schema and we will correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You create an Enumeration with EnumerationLiteal, see image. Did you really look on the net before asking your question ? And next time, at least provide a "try".
[image]